# When I read a file in utf-8 .find() doesn't work

Tags: python-3.x, utf-8

I'm trying to read this file (stored in file "apartadoB.txt")

I've written that code but it doesn't work (nothing is printed)

```
file = open("apartadoB.txt","rb")

for i in file.readlines():

    i = str(i.decode('utf-8','ignore'))

    if i.find('Respuesta') != -1:
        print(i)
 
file.close()
```

apartadoB.txt:

> �� Haciendo ping a 10.3.7.0 con 572 bytes de datos: Respuesta desde
> 10.3.7.0: bytes=572 tiempo=228ms TTL=253
>
> Estad�sticas de ping para 10.3.7.0:
> Paquetes: enviados = 1, recibidos = 1, perdidos = 0
> (0% perdidos), Tiempos aproximados de ida y vuelta en milisegundos:
> M�nimo = 228ms, M�ximo = 228ms, Media = 228ms
>
> Haciendo ping a 10.4.2.5 con 572 bytes de datos: Respuesta desde
> 10.4.2.5: bytes=572 tiempo=11ms TTL=254
>
> Estad�sticas de ping para 10.4.2.5:
> Paquetes: enviados = 1, recibidos = 1, perdidos = 0
> (0% perdidos), Tiempos aproximados de ida y vuelta en milisegundos:
> M�nimo = 11ms, M�ximo = 11ms, Media = 11ms
>
> Haciendo ping a 10.3.7.0 con 572 bytes de datos: Respuesta desde
> 10.3.7.0: bytes=572 tiempo=225ms TTL=253
>
> Estad�sticas de ping para 10.3.7.0:
> Paquetes: enviados = 1, recibidos = 1, perdidos = 0
> (0% perdidos), Tiempos aproximados de ida y vuelta en milisegundos:
> M�nimo = 225ms, M�ximo = 225ms, Media = 225ms
>
> . . .

Comment: This code works for me and gives the proper output. I copied the contents of apartadoB.txt and created the file and ran your code.  Is this code part of a function or a larger code piece ? If so, please share the entire function as this part does not have any error

Comment: Well I don't know why but it should be an error with the file (apartadoB.txt). Because I've just copied the content into another text file and my code is working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the following data encoded as UTF-8 to `apartadoB.txt`:

```
Haciendo ping a 10.3.7.0 con 572 bytes de datos: Respuesta desde 10.3.7.0: bytes=572 tiempo=228ms TTL=253
Estadísticas de ping para 10.3.7.0: Paquetes: enviados = 1, recibidos = 1, perdidos = 0 (0% perdidos), Tiempos aproximados de ida y vuelta en milisegundos: Mínimo = 228ms, Máximo = 228ms, Media = 228ms
Haciendo ping a 10.4.2.5 con 572 bytes de datos: Respuesta desde 10.4.2.5: bytes=572 tiempo=11ms TTL=254
Estadísticas de ping para 10.4.2.5: Paquetes: enviados = 1, recibidos = 1, perdidos = 0 (0% perdidos), Tiempos aproximados de ida y vuelta en milisegundos: Mínimo = 11ms, Máximo = 11ms, Media = 11ms
Haciendo ping a 10.3.7.0 con 572 bytes de datos: Respuesta desde 10.3.7.0: bytes=572 tiempo=225ms TTL=253
Estadísticas de ping para 10.3.7.0: Paquetes: enviados = 1, recibidos = 1, perdidos = 0 (0% perdidos), Tiempos aproximados de ida y vuelta en milisegundos: Mínimo = 225ms, Máximo = 225ms, Media = 225ms
```

The following code is recommended to read it:

- `with` automatically closes the file.
- `open` should be in text mode (the default) and specify the encoding.
- `readlines()` is not needed.  Iterate directly over the file.
- lines (`i`) will be already decoded with UTF-8.
- `end=''` because `i` lines will already have a newline.

---

```
with open('apartadoB.txt',encoding='utf8') as file:
    for i in file:
        if i.find('Respuesta') != -1:
            print(i)
```

Output:

```
Haciendo ping a 10.3.7.0 con 572 bytes de datos: Respuesta desde 10.3.7.0: bytes=572 tiempo=228ms TTL=253
Haciendo ping a 10.4.2.5 con 572 bytes de datos: Respuesta desde 10.4.2.5: bytes=572 tiempo=11ms TTL=254
Haciendo ping a 10.3.7.0 con 572 bytes de datos: Respuesta desde 10.3.7.0: bytes=572 tiempo=225ms TTL=253
```

Comment: Thanks but when I use your code I get the following error: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte. And if I use errors='ignore', I get 0 outputs

Comment: Well I don't know why but it should be an error with the file (apartadoB.txt). Because I've just copied the content into another text file and my code is working

Comment: @Veggy the file must be saved in UTF-8. If it starts with FF it is more likely saved as UTF-16.